# Accessing values in Map through EL in JSF2

Tags: dictionary, jsf-2, el

Versions :

Aapche MyFaces 2.1.14

RichFaces 4.3.5

Issue :

I have a class implementing map interface like below :

```
public class FormStore implements Map {


    private Map values; 


    public Object get(Object key) {

        return values.get(key);
    }

    public Object put(Object key, Object value) {

        return values.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

I am using this map to store all submitted form values in my application and accessing in facelet as shown in below facelet code :

```
 <h:inputText id="phone" value="#{formStore['phone']}" size="12" maxlength="20" required="true">
```

where `formStore` is the java class above.

Now I have added another Map in above java class as below which serves some special purpose.

```
public class FormStore implements Map {


private Map values; 
private Map additionalValues;


public Object get(Object key) {

    return values.get(key);
}

public Object put(Object key, Object value) {

    return values.put(key, value);
}
//getter and setter method for additionalValues also added
```

}

The issue is I am not able to access this new map from EL . I have tried following options  :

```
1)<h:inputText id="phone" value="#{formStore.additionalValues['phone']}" size="12" maxlength="20" required="true">
2)<h:inputText id="phone" value="#{formStore.[additionalValues]['phone']}" size="12" maxlength="20" required="true">
3)<h:inputText id="phone" value="#{formStore[additionalValues]['phone']}" size="12" maxlength="20" required="true">
```

For every option , it calls FormStore.get method with `key = additionalValues`

Is it not possible to access the additionalValues map from `FormStore.java` class ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<h:inputText id="phone" value="#{formStore.getAdditionalValues()['phone']}" size="12" maxlength="20" required="true">
```